# diagrama de classes e projeto de banco de dados no Visual Studio online

Tags: visual-studio-online

Como posso criar um diagrama de classes e um projeto de banco de dados no Visual Studio online? Ou está disponível apenas para versão ultimate do Visual  Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo Visual Studio Online não existem esses recursos. [Aqui está a lista de recursos até a data desta resposta](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx).

Estes recursos normalmente são mesmo do Visual Studio Ultimate. [Há também o Entity Developer Express](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1C10C16E-7F9E-4447-B9D6-D61C7357CA30) que funciona da mesma forma para versões Express e Community do Visual Studio.